# EditText overflowing into button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in my fragment activity.

I'm facing two issues.

**1)** I cannot put the `Button`, exactly below the `EditText`.

Here, is the screenshot :

[image]

**2)** Whenever I paste lengthy text in the `EditText`, button is overlapping with the text. See this screenshot:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
      <FrameLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:text="@string/URL"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Track"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    
       </FrameLayout>
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a FrameLayout, you might want to consider using a RelativeLayout. Then you can do the following:

For the EditText, use the following attribute:

```
// This says the widget should be vertically and horizontally at the center of the container
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

For the Button, use the following attribute:

```
android:layout_below:"@id/editText"
```

The attributes that I have mentioned will replace the

> android:layout_gravity

attributes for both the widgets you have used.

Also the EditText will lose the

> android:layout_marginTop="200dp"

attribute as the layout_centerInParent attribute will automatically center it.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil. It worked. Both issues resolved. Should I also use<LinearLayout> inside of my <RelativeLayout>?

Comment: No, you should not. LinearLayout follows it's own design principle in an "eldest child wins" approach. In RelativeLayout, later children are higher in the Z-axis - this has it's own pattern. For your purpose, RelativeLayout is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout. The purpose of FrameLayout is to display **one** item.

Answer (score 1):

This is pseudo code but help you to understand the structure

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    orientation=vertical
    centerInParent= true
    >

       <EditText/>
       <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```